# Invalid operation: Invalid AVRO file

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark, amazon-redshift

I am trying to source data from MySQL db into a PySpark dataframe and load it into a Redshift table. While loading tables, any tables that have a decimal field in it is erring out the error "

**

> java.sql.SQLException: Amazon Invalid operation: Invalid AVRO file

"
Has anyone faced an issue like this before?
One workaround I did is to convert this decimal field into a Float and then load it. That works, but if the table has 10 different decimal fields then this solution becomes cumbersome. Any thoughts? inputs?

Comment: Any help guys? i am like a dead fish in the water :(